# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load sqlitejdbc from loader

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, javafxports

I was trying to store data in JavaFX running on Android using SQLite database but somehow I cant seem to make it work! Im stuck with this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load sqlitejdbc from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.rameses-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.rameses-1]: findLibrary returned null
   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
   at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.<clinit>(NativeDB.java:35)
   at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:180)
   at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:74)
   at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:24)
   at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:23)
   at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
   at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
   at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:144)
   at com.rameses.waterworks.database.Database.getConnection(Database.java:34)
   at com.rameses.waterworks.database.Database.initTables(Database.java:44)
   at com.rameses.Main.start(Main.java:33)
   at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$144(LauncherImpl.java:863)
   at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$9.run(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$157(PlatformImpl.java:326)
   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$7.run(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$155(PlatformImpl.java:295)
   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$19.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:52)
   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$156(PlatformImpl.java:294)
   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$6.run(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)
   at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)
```

Can somebody tell me what this error is? How do I resolve this? Please help!

Comment: @José Pereda, Sir, do you have any idea about this error?

Comment: Hi, from what i see, is the DalvikVm can't find or load sqlite. I gave up for trying ti embedding sqllite on JavaFXPorts apps. Maybe you should try H2 Database. It's fully written in Java and it should much more easy to work with JavaFX Apps. Regards, Ivan